# What is the expected write-speed drop for SSDs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

Basically, the problem is this:
An external SSD (SATA drive in an enclosure) drops the write speed after some time when uploading large files/ a lot of files.
I first noticed this when just uploading a backup of around 140GB. After a minute or so, the speed dropped from the expected 350+ MB/s to around 80 MB/s.

The same is observed in CrystalDiskMark 8. Using a test file of 1GiB, all speeds are as expected. Using a file of 64GiB, the write speed is registered at ~80MB/s (Screenshots attached).

After doing some research, I got the impression that the speed gets lower because the buffer (cache) fills up, and then the process slows down. So my question is - **what is the expected drop?** If I have an SSD connected with USB 3.0 that should be able to reach speeds of up to 400MB/s, I'd expect that value (or one close to that) for all file sizes.

Additionally, if this is not normal - could this be the external enclosure's controller's fault, or at least - could it be less severe with another controller?
If it is normal, are there maybe some programs who help avoid this issue? Like queuing the files to allow the cache to empty itself and get back to the full speed (if this is even possible :DD)
Thank you all in advance.

[image: 1GiB][image: 64GiB]

Comment: That’s 100% specific to the drive model.

Comment: Just to start with: What kind of flash does the SSD use (is it TLC or is it cheap QLC) and how much internal cache (DRAM cache, SLC cache, etc) does it have for buffering writes before they hit the actual flash? The "expected" numbers will vary _massively_ between a QLC SSD and a TLC SSD, just because of how slow QLC actually is.

Comment: Yes. It s normal. SSDs have fast caches that you fill up and then performance drops off a cliff until the cache is emptied. https://www.techpowerup.com/review/solidigm-p44-pro-2-tb-1-tb/6.html has a good list of drives and their cache sizes.